# Async and RecyclerView to display list while fetching data

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I'm new to Android

And I'm having a problem with displaying the list items in the RecyclerView.
I was hoping to display the list one by one and append while it is still loading.

But what happens is, the list will appear after all the items are fetched.

Here is my Fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lock_list, container, false)
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)

        for(device in devices) {
            fetchBuildingAddress(device)
        }

        if (recyclerView is RecyclerView) {
            with(recyclerView) {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                adapter = deviceRecyclerViewAdapter
            }
        }

        return view
    }


    private fun fetchBuildingAddress(device: Device) {
        deviceWearableService.getBuilding(device.buildingId) {
            when(it) {
                is DeviceWearableServiceImpl.State.Success -> {
                    val buildingName = it.resources.buildingAddress.address1

                    val deviceBuilding = DeviceBuillding(device, buildingName)
                    deviceRecyclerViewAdapter.insertDevice(deviceBuilding)
                }
            else -> {
                    // TODO: ERROR STATE
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

And in my `insertDevice`
I simply call the `notifyItemInserted` in the adapter.

```
fun insertDevice(updateDeviceBuilding: DeviceBuillding) {
    deviceBuilding.add(updateDeviceBuilding)
    notifyItemInserted(deviceBuilding.size - 1 )
}
```

You could also suggest what is the better behavior! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: That might because `deviceWearableService.getBuilding` because  you are calling it inside loop one after another without any delay so all the items gets loaded at once probably in few miliseconds difference  .  How long does it takes to load one time ? What exactly is `deviceWearableService.getBuilding`? does it takes fixed time to execute or random  ?

Comment: Hello! You might be right since it only gets the building details. It is an API. I wonder how this should be approached.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear that you are fetching paged data or complete data , but what you need is to use `flow` with a Diff callback in your adapter i.e `PagingDataAdapter`([example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/insight/adapter/RecyclerViewListAdapter.kt#L13)) or `ListAdatper`([example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/main/adapter/RecyclerViewTodoAdapter.kt#L12)).

Its implementation is quite easy you can find it on net.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try this. But It's not a paged data :( what I did is I just split what i received.